# glsl arc not rotating properly around a circle

Tags: math, geometry, glsl, webgl

I have tried creating a shader that has an arc that rotates around a circle, you can see an example here:

https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MljGDK

```
#define center vec2(0.5)
#define pi 3.1415926535897932384626433832795
#define resolution 250.0
#define arcColor vec4(0.1, 0.2, 0.9, 1.0)

vec4 arc(vec2 uv, vec2 pos, float radius, float angle, vec4 color) {
    vec2 b = (pos * resolution - uv * resolution);
    float d = 1.0 - clamp(length(b) - radius * resolution, 0.0, 1.0);
    float a1 = atan(-b.x, -b.y);
    float a2 = atan(b.x, b.y);
    //return color * smoothstep(0.0, d, angle - a);
    return color * (a2 >= radians(angle) - pi / 8.0 && a2 <= radians(angle) + pi / 8.0 ? d : 0.0);
}

vec4 circle(vec2 uv, vec2 pos, float radius, vec4 color) {
    float d = length(pos * resolution - uv * resolution) - radius * resolution;
    float t = clamp(d, 0.0, 1.0);
    return color * (1.0 - t);
}

void mainImage ( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord ) {
    vec2 uv = fragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;
    vec4 arcSection = arc(uv, center, 0.5, mod(iGlobalTime*100.0, 360.0), arcColor);
    vec4 hole = circle(uv, center, 0.45, vec4(1.0));
    fragColor = arcSection - hole;
}
```

However, I do not know why the atan is returning values which cut off the arc at the poles of the circle.  I was under the impression that atan(x, y) in glsl is implemented as atan2.

Any help in either improving the arc rotation or making the algorithm cleaner would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ... and you're allowing for the fact that it's `atan(y, x)`, not `atan(x, y)`?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is failure to allow for the circular nature of results. In the abstract: how far is an angle of 0.0 degrees from an angle of 359.0? According to your code, it's 359 degrees away rather than 1 degree away.

Suggested alternative:

```
float a2Diff = mod(radians(angle) - a2, pi * 2.0);

return color * ((a2Diff >= pi * 15.0 / 8.0 || a2Diff <= pi / 8.0) ? d : 0.0);
```

So you're computing the difference between the two angles, creating a fixed centre, and then allowing for potential wraparound with the `mod`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be careful with the wraparound in order to treat angles close to 2*pi as being close to 0. Here's a working code example:

```
#define center vec2(0.5, 0.5)
#define pi 3.1415926535897932384626433832795
#define resolution 250.0
#define arcColor vec4(0.1, 0.2, 0.9, 1.0)

vec4 arc(vec2 uv, vec2 pos, float radius1, float radius2, float angle, vec4 color) {
    vec2 b = (pos * resolution - uv * resolution);
    float angdist = mod(atan(b.x, b.y) - angle, 2.0*pi);
    return color * ((angdist < pi/8.0)
                    && (length(b) >= radius1 * resolution)
                    && (length(b) <= radius2 * resolution) ? 1.0 : 0.0);
}

void mainImage ( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord ) {
    vec2 uv = fragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;
    vec4 arcSection = arc(uv, center, 0.45, 0.5, radians(mod(iGlobalTime*100.0, 360.0)), arcColor);
    fragColor = arcSection;
}
```